# Django 1.7 on Heroku: how do I get makemigrations to rescan the database?

Tags: django, heroku, django-migrations

I have Django 1.7 running on Heroku. I've made a change to the models.py file (added a column to a table) but Django doesn't seem to be able to detect this. When I run

```
python manage.py makemigrations appname
```

it responds No changes detected in app.

I've tried deleting the appname/migrations folder, but that doesn't help.

Is there a way to get Django to rescan the database and check for differences? This was easy with South.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#the-commands

Have you tried

```
python manage.py migrate
```

It seems the migrate is "responsible for applying migrations, as well as unapplying and listing their status."